# The question of irregular verbs

Tags: verbs, irregular-forms

I study English 3-4 days.

The irregular form of the verb will use affirmative form in the past tense.

And if there is no such verb?

Let the words `Open` and `Close`

And if I understood correctly, it means that if there is no irregular verb form and the word ends with the vowel `e`, then I must add `d` to the end of the word, and if the word ends with a consonant, then `ed`.

Do I think correctly?

> OpenED
>
> CloseD

Comment: Yes. But this mute <e> would be deleted in the gerund-participle form "closing". Note also that, usually, it's a matter of pronunciation rather than spelling. "Stomach" takes /s/ in the plural because the final consonant is /k/. "Coach" takes /ɪz/ because the final consonant is /tʃ/.

Comment: I understand you, thank you ...

Comment: This is not a rule that applies to every verb—and certainly not every irregular verb. (Neither *open* nor *close* is an irregular verb.) For instance, the past tense of *bury* (a regular verb) is *buried*, not *buryd*. And the past tense of *beat* (an irregular verb) is *beat*.

Comment: Thank you, Jason Bassford, I understand you